# Page doesn't automatically update when socket.io receive

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I want to page update when new socket.io data appear.
I have a server -> client comunication:
Server code (the n var is the message)

```
io2.on('connection', function(socket2) {  
    socket2.on('live', function(data2) {
    console.log('status from live client:', data2);
    socket2.emit('live', n);
});
});
```

Live page code:

```
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3002');
    socket.emit('live', 'live client is connected');
    socket.on('live', function(data) {
        //alert(data)
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data;

    });
```

The socket works fine because when I send the data and I refresh the page it show what I want. The problem is that I want to see the updated message without manual refresh.

Thanks!

Comment: in the first block `n` is undefined. Try initializing it

Comment: n is the message received from another socket. It is initialized because I receive in live client the correct message, but it doesn't update automatic

Comment: Your creating two `socket.io` server ? Are you using `namespaces` ?

Comment: yes. I'm using 2 sockets because I want a client->server->another client comunication. And I have some problems with socket.io listen ports and it didn't worked, so I used 2 different sockets and that seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to emit the event from server side to the client side and then catch data there

```
var server = app.listen(3000);  
var io = require('socket.io')(server);


io.on('connection', function(socket) {  
  socket.on('event', function(data) {
    var n = data.message;
    io.sockets.emit('event', message);

});
```

And then on frontend in live page you write this

```
var n = <%-JSON.stringify(v1)%>;
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
socket.on('event', (data)=>{
     console.log(data)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The scope for n is undefined in the first function, so the receiving function doesn't have anything to show.

You'll need to define n in the original emitting function.

Comment: io.on('connection', function(socket) {  
    socket.on('event', function(data) {
        console.log('A client sent us this dumb message:', data.message);
        var n = data.message;
        console.log("");
        console.log("data received from play client..trying to send to live");
        console.log("");
        console.log("var n is");
        console.log(n);
        console.log("sending data...");

Comment: --> n is from another socket and it is defined and it works. The problem is that the page doesn't update automatic. The socket works and I receive the message in live client bu t I have to refresh page manual